# Converting Double type column to date format type pyspark retuning

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with double column (`20180310`), i want to convert it to Date format (`2018-03-10`).

I used this function:

```py
df.withColumn(
    "new_col", 
    F.to_date(F.col("old_col").cast("string"), "yyyyMMdd")
)
```

but it's returning error message or Null.

Do you have any idea please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you cast from double to string, the column will have this form: `2.018031E7`

cast to integer before casting to string:

```
df.withColumn( "new_col", F.to_date(F.col("old_col").cast("integer").cast("string"), "yyyyMMdd"))
```